# Predict the Bomb's Landing Point!

Tags: code-golf, physics

## Introduction

It was just a normal day, here at your military base. Suddenly, you looked up to see a bomb falling down from the sky! You need to create a program to predict where it will fall, and tell you the location.

## Challenge

You will be given a bomb in the form of `Start-X Start-Y X-velocity Y-velocity`. You can assume that they will all be positive integers. 0 is a valid input only for `Start-x` and `Start-y`. The bomb starts with x `Start-x`, and y `Start-y`. Each "frame" (no graphical output required), the bomb will move `x-velocity` units right, then `y-velocity` units down. Continue doing this until the bomb reaches y of 0 or below. Then, output what it's x was when it hit the ground.

## Test Cases

1

Input:`0 10 2 2`

Output:`10`

2

Input:`5 4 3 2`

Output:`11`

3

Input:`11,8,7,3`

Output:`32`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Once you do out the math, it looks like the formula leaves little to golf.

Comment: @xnor Maybe the ceiling function could be golfed. But I can't see anywhere else.

Comment: `You can assume that they will all be positive integers` 0 is not a positive integer. Can you clarify if 0 is a valid input or not?

Comment: Looks like 0 is valid input from test case #1

Comment: 0 is a valid input only for start-x and start-y. editing now.

Comment: Since this is such a trivial question, please [do not upvote answers in obvious or golfing languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10132/62824).

Comment: "Normal day", "military base" being in your "military base" isnt "normal". also, If you make a military base you might as well make it an explosion-proof bunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 05AB1E, 9 bytes

```
¹³²(I÷(*+
```

[Try online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39o56HNhzZpeB7erqGl/f@/KZcJlzGXEQA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

Thanks @user5090812 for golfing off 1 byte

```javascript
(a,b,x,y)=>a+x*((b+y-1)/y|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9r5Gok6RToVOpaWuXqF2h5ZtYkqGXnJqZo5GkX6n5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DQMfQQMdIx0RT8z8A)

If it did not have to move x then y but was instead falling in a straight line it would be 18 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,x,y)=>a+x*b/y
```

Comment: You could do `(a,b,x,y)=>a+x*(b/y|0+1)` and save 5 bytes

Comment: @powelles If I do that I will end up overshooting for exact values.

Comment: Weird. I expected `x|0+1` to perform the same as `Math.ceil` and didn't actually test it.

Comment: @powelles if you have 1|0+1 you end up with 2. With Math.ceil you will get 1

Comment: I mistakenly made the assumption that ceiling could be implemented as floor+1.

Comment: There is a way to emulate ceiling with integer math, but in this case it saves only 1 byte: `(a,b,x,y)=>a+x*((b+y-1)/y|0)`

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 21 bytes

```
Input :Prompt A,B:X+A+Aint(Y/B-E~9
```

If the ceiling function did not have to be implemented, it would be more straightforward at 13 bytes:

```
Input :Prompt A,B:X+AY/B
```

Comment: Don't you need to prompt for x and y as well?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk In TI-83/84 BASIC, providing no arguments to `Input` is equivalent to `Prompt X,Y`, taking location from the graph screen. It's usually more of a savings when only one or two values are needed, although it saves 1 byte in this situation as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <del>45</del> 28 Bytes

```
lambda a,b,x,y:a+x*-(-b//y)
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/GuwM/1)

Comment: The import has to be scored. [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8287/34718)

Comment: @mbomb007 Still, with the import is 45 bytes

Comment: Why not use your own `ceil` function? `lambda a,b,x,y:a+x*int(b/y+.5)`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Just made one 2 bytes shorter than yours

Comment: `a--b//y*x` seems to work.

Comment: If you use Python 2, I think you can eliminate the `//` and just put `/`.

Comment: Combining ØrjanJohansen's suggestions and my suggestion: `lambda a,b,x,y:a--b/y*x` in Python 2 for 23 bytes.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem wouldn't that do a `round`? a `ceil` is `(b+y-1)/y`

Comment: You could use `a-x*(...)` to save 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme <del>40</del> 36 Bytes

```
λ(x y u v)(+ x(* u(ceiling(/ y v))))
```

Comment: Does scheme require all of those spaces between identifiers and parentheses

Comment: Actually I can get rid of some of them...thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 21 bytes

```
(a#b)x y=a-x*div(-b)y
```

The trivial answer: defines an operator that takes 4 arguments and then uses the formula.

Could probably be golfed more.

EDIT: Yep, Ørjan Johansen points out we can use `a-x*div b(-y)`, which brings us to 22 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@6@RqJykWaFQaZuoW6GVklmmkKShW6n5PzcxM882JV@hoCgzr0RBRUHDQNnQQNNIwYhLAQrgMqbKJprG2CQMDZUtNM0VjP8DAA)

At this point, the code is really more other people than mine, so I'm going to mark this answer community wiki. Feel free to golf this further if you want :)

Comment: Ouch, importing `Data.Ratio` ... try `a-x*div(-b)y`.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 46 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>a+c*(int)Math.Ceiling((double)b/d);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 21 bytes

```
->x,y,v,w{x-v*(y/-w)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 66 bytes

```
int f(int a,int b,int x,int y){return a+x*(int)Math.ceil(1f*b/y);}
```